# How to use ggplot for multiple rows into one plot-graphic

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

to be honest, I think it is a stupid and easy question for a R expert.
However, I've had the problem for hours, and haven't really come up with a solution...

I have data from a survey that asked if someone has already used a voice assistant (1 = using, 2 = not using; factor) and how they would like to communicate with a system (1 = would use, 0 = would not use; numeric). Since multiple choices were possible in the communication question, I separated the answers into individual columns.

```
#row Assistant Touchdisplay Mobile Voice
   1         1            0      1     1
   2         2            1      0     0
   3         1            1      1     1
   4         1            1      0     1
```

**Now I would like to show how people who already use a voice assistant and people who haven't used a voice assistant have answered.**

I have tried:

```
ggplot(data) + geom_bar(aes(Touchdisplay==1, , fill = Assistent), position = "dodge")
```

[image]

And that's almost what I need. But only the right side (TRUE) and not only for the touch display but also for all other methods in one plot-graphic.

I'm sure it's pretty easy for an R expert and I've tried everything I can think of and I'm currently missing a starting point to solve it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be looking for this? As is often the case, you need to reshape your data first:

```
data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -Assistant) %>% 
  filter(value != 0) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = name, fill = factor(Assistant))) +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(preserve = 'single'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
data <- structure(list(Assistant = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), Touchdisplay = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), Mobile = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Voice = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

The code:

```
data %>% pivot_longer(cols = -Assistant) %>% filter(value!=0) %>%
  group_by(Assistant,name) %>% summarise(val=sum(value)) %>%
  filter(name=='Touchdisplay') %>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',aes(x=name,y=val,fill=factor(Assistant)),position=position_dodge())
```

Output:

[image]

In that way you could also add other devices changing the code `filter(name=='Touchdisplay')`.

```
data %>% pivot_longer(cols = -Assistant) %>% filter(value!=0) %>%
  group_by(Assistant,name) %>% summarise(val=sum(value)) %>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',aes(x=name,y=val,fill=factor(Assistant)),position=position_dodge())
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I thought that the OP wanted to only plot the 1s for each category after filtering for `Assistant==1`, so maybe this is what you're after?

first, some data:

```
set.seed(22447)
data <- data.frame(Assistant=factor(sample(1:2, size=100, replace=T)), 
                   Touchdisplay=sample(0:1, size=100, replace=T),
                   Mobile=sample(0:1, size=100, replace=T), 
                   Voice=sample(0:1, size=100, replace=T))
```

this is what your original plot looks like with this example data:

```
ggplot(data) + geom_bar(aes(Touchdisplay==1, fill = Assistant), 
                        position = "dodge")
```

[image]

and now filtering, pivoting to longer, and summarizing:

```
ds <- data %>% filter(Assistant==1) %>% pivot_longer(-Assistant) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% summarize(total=sum(value))

ds
```

the output of summarize:

```
        # A tibble: 3 x 2
      name         total
      <chr>        <int>
    1 Mobile          26
    2 Touchdisplay    26
    3 Voice           19
```

plotting the 1s using `geom_col()`:

```
ggplot(ds) + geom_col(aes(name, total))
```

[image]